# Parse(byte[]) cannot be applied to java.lang.string

Tags: java, android

Trying to parse data to establish a connection between a device and a test server.  Except, I get a red line on `(toParse)` within `String parsedMessage = (String)comm.parse(toParse).getPayload();` with the error `parse(byte[]) in Communicator cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)`

I have tried to change `String toParse` to `byte[] toParse` and it makes the red line go away for `parse(toParse)` but the `byte[] toParse` turns red instead with the error "required byte[], found java.lang.String"

```
Communicator comm = new 
Communicatior(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
String toParse = "88819188181A7";
String parsedMessage = (String)comm.parse(toParse).getPayload();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to invoke the method getBytes() like this:

```
String parsedMessage = (String)comm.parse(toParse.getBytes()).getPayload();
```

Comment: I ran a test and I got this error ``java.lang.ClassCastException: byte[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String`` for the line ``String parsedMessage = (String)comm.parse(toParse.getBytes()).getPayload();``

Comment: Can you tell me what is the return type of the method getPayload()?

Comment: Sure, it is a String.  String type.